# You've voted for this as a useful comment

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, комментарии

Подсказка при голосе за комментарий не переведена:

[image: скриншот дефекта локализации]

> You've voted for this as a useful comment

Comment: Туда же, когда нет голоса:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jBcr.png

Comment: И когда кто-то редактирует пост тоже сообщение на английском

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Перевод добавлен:

> Вы сочли этот комментарий полезным и проголосовали за него

Изменения отобразятся по синхронизации переводов.

Спасибо за помощь!